# How to set my ColumnDefinition after togglebutton click

Tags: wpf

So i have this `Grid`:

```
<Grid>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ColumnDefinition Width="{DynamicResource IsSelectedGrigWidth}"/>

<ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>

 <ColumnDefinition Width="780"/>

 <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>

</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Column="0">

 <CheckBox Name="checkBoxIsSelected"

            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"

            Checked="checkBoxIsSelected_Checked"                                                                              

            Unchecked="checkBoxIsSelected_Unchecked"

            Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

 </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And when my `ToggleButton IsChecked` i want my first `Column` become with `Width` of `30`.

So i create this:

```
<system1:GridLength x:Key="IsSelectedGrigWidth">0</system1:GridLength>
```

And when my `ToggleButton IsChecked`:

```
Resources["IsSelectedGrigWidth"] = new GridLength(30);
```

And when my `ToggleButton IsUnchecked`:

```
Resources["IsSelectedGrigWidth"] = new GridLength(0);
```

So this not working and my `Column` `Width` is still `0`

Any idea why ?

Comment: suggestion: you can use `ActualWidth` instead of `Width` which is a double. BTW how can you see the checkbox if its length is 0?